# One line output for two 'print' lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to programming and I have a question as if there's a way to get one line output for two 'print' lines.

Ex:

```
end1 = ("A")
end2 = ("B")
end3 = ("C")
end4 = ("D")
print (end1 + end2,)
print (end3 + end4)
```

Response currently is

```
AB
CD
```

Is there a way to get response in one line with two 'print' input lines?

```
AB CD
```

Comment: `print(end1 + end2, end=' ')` or `print(end1 + end2, end3 + end4)`

Comment: In what situation do you need this? What is the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(end1 + end2 + ' ' + end3 + end4)
```

OR

```
print('{:s}{:s} {:s}{:s}'.format('A','B','C','D'))
```

OR

```
print(end1 + end2, end=" ")
print(end3 + end4)
```

If you don't want the last line to output a newline, you can add `end=""` to it. In general, the default `end` argument of `print` is `\n` but you can change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

default end value is `\n` , You can define your own end
Try this

```
print (end1 + end2,end="")

print (end3 + end4,end="")
```